# PHP Method Chaining and Strings

Tags: php, method-chaining

This is an interesting quirk I found while method chaining and I'm having difficulty bypassing it. I'm sure there's a solution or another way. It's tough to explain but I'll do my best.

Example:

You have three functions which are part of a class, as well as 2 protected properties as follows.

```
class Chain {

  protected $_str  = '';
  protected $_part = 0;

  public function __toString() {
    return implode(' ', $this->_str);
  }

  public function AAA () {
    $this->_str[$this->_part] = 'AAA';
    $this->_part++;
    return $this;
  }

  public function BBB () {
    $this->_str[$this->_part] = 'BBB';
    $this->_part++;
    return $this;
  }

  public function wrap ($str) {
    $part = $this->_part - 1;
    $this->_str[$part] = "({$str})";
    return $this;
  }

}
```

Now when chaining these methods and specifically using the wrap method, the strings from previous chains are unintentionally appended. Example:

```
$chain = new Chain();
$chain->AAA()->BBB()->wrap($chain->AAA());
echo $chain;
```

What you would expect the string to look like is `AAA BBB (AAA)`.

However, what actually returns is `AAA BBB (AAA BBB AAA)`.

Why is it that `wrap()` takes all the previous methods called within the chain instead of only the method that's actually wrapped by it? What is the best way around this assuming there is one?

Comment: Here is a thought: stop chaining methods, it's a bad practice.

Comment: `$this->_query[$part] = "({$str})";` probably supposed to be `$this->_str[$part] = "({$str})";`

Comment: @tereško Your thought is completely subjective and chaining can be either good or bad depending on the situation.

Comment: here is a quick flowchart for decision to use chaining : http://i.stack.imgur.com/WjT6C.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$chain->AAA()->BBB()` is doing the  first two 'AAA' and 'BBB' - obvious.
Then the `$chain->AAA()` which comes inside `wrap($chain->AAA())` does the 3rd 'AAA'.
and last, the `wrap` method takes all the three and wraps them with `()` and concatenated to the first 'AAA' and 'BBB' using this line: `$this->_str[$part] = "({$str})";`  
which resolves to: `AAA BBB (AAA BBB AAA).`

**UPDATE:**
I believe that what you're trying to do, is to avoid the side-effect of returning `this` from methods `AAA()` and `BBB()` - will be achieved with the following changes:

```
<?php
class Chain {

  protected $_str  = '';
  protected $_part = 0;

  public function __toString() {
    return implode(' ', $this->_str);
  }

  public function AAA () {
    $this->_str[$this->_part] = 'AAA';
    $this->_part++;
    return "AAA";
  }

  public function BBB () {
    $this->_str[$this->_part] = 'BBB';
    $this->_part++;
    return "BBB";
  }

  public function wrap ($str) {
    $part = $this->_part - 1;
    $this->_str[$part] = "({$str})";
    return $str;
  }

}

$chain = new Chain();
$chain->AAA();
$chain->BBB();
$chain->wrap($chain->AAA());
echo $chain->__toString();

?>
```

Comment: Yes I'm well aware of what it's doing by my given output... WHY is it taking all previous methods as an argument when only one is passed and what is a good way to avoid it is my question.

Comment: I explained it in my answer: the line `$this->_str[$part] = "({$str})";` is taking EVERYTHING which is currently in `$this->_str` and wraps it with  `()`

Comment: See, the method `$chain->AAA()` returns `this`. Try calling: `echo $chain->AAA();` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks. I would expect it to NOT add the others because only one of the methods is within the wrap. By looking at it, I wouldn't expect the previous calls to jump inside and be appended, chained or not. I realize separating them would give a different output, however it seems odd to me.

Comment: @Baez you can change the method `AAA()` to return 'AAA' instead of returning `$this` (same thing to `BBB()` of course) - I believe that it would solve your problem. side-effects sucks ... ;)

Comment: @Baez I think that I understand what you're trying to do, check out the `UPDATE` section in my answer and let me know if that's what you meant.

Comment: Yeah I was actually thinking of doing something like that. Only problem is the chain will have to break when hitting those methods since strings are passed. Thanks for the help it's appreciated. Add in your other comment I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it kind of a 'race condition'. It seems PHP first interprets the `$chain->AAA()->BBB()`.

Then `$chain->_part` is 2 and `$chain->_str` is 'AAA BBB'.

Then, to be able to call wrap, the argument, so `$chain->AAA()` is run.

Then `$chain->_part` is 3 and `$chain->_str` is 'AAA BBB AAA'.

Finally wrap is called, warpping up the 'AAA BBB AAA'. I would seperate the wrap()-call and reset `$chain->_part` back to zero in between.

Comment: This is a good walkthrough, however it still seems like wrap() should only take the methods you pass as arguments even when being chained. The problem is, with unchaining not being an option, how do you go about avoiding it? Seems like there is no solution.

Comment: Well, actually you could write a function XYZ where you reset _part to zero. This way, you don't have to unchain and still reset _part at the right time using $chain->AAA()->BBB()->XYZ()->wrap($chain->AAA());

Answer (score 0):

The calling queue is:

```
1. $chain->AAA() //this is first method not in wrap() method, you have now AAA
2. $chain->BBB() //then next method, you have now AAA BBB
3. $chain->AAA() //again AAA() method inside wrap method, so you have AAA BBB AAA
```

inside the `wrap()` you are putting chain(which is AAA BBB AAA after 3rd step) string in () so you have AAA BBB AAA string at the end of  `_part` array.